# Bind json or json array to grails object

Tags: json, grails, groovy

I've got response as json array

```
['1', '1', '2']
```

or as json array of objects

```
[{'name': 'blabla', age: '30'}, {'name': 'lala', age: '35'}]
```

And I would like to arrays to grails objects, what grails features can I use in this case?

I'm looking at **command objects**, but also found `@Validatable` annotation.

What to use for binding json to grails object (**without persistence**)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm looking at command objects, but also found @Validatable annotation.

These are really the same thing. A class annotated `@Validateable` is a command object. The only time you don't need to annotate a command object with `@Validateable` is if it's in the same file as a controller class (you can have more than one class in the same file in Groovy).

A command object is the recommended way to bind JSON to a Groovy object if you don't intent to persist it.

Comment: thanks, already found in documentation that command objects already validatable

Answer (score 0):

If that names of the JSON properties match up to the names of the Groovy Object properties then you can use a syntax like this:

**Groovy class**

```
class Person {
    String name
    Integer age
}
```

**JSON**

```
{'name': 'John Snow', 'age': 30}
```

**Controller/Service**

```
assert json == [name: 'John Snow', age: 30]

def person = new Person(json)

// or...

def person = new Person()
person.properties = json
```

Comment: Can I use `Person` like command object? E.g. action in controller: `def update(Person person) {}`

Comment: What to do in case, where I have json array without keys?

Comment: Generally, when passed as a parameter to a controller action, command classes are treated as command objects. In fact, it can be said that domain class objects are a kind of command objects. @havenchyk